# Passing credentials to Peoplesoft web service from ASP.NET using SOAP headers

Tags: asp.net, web-services, peoplesoft

I have looked all over the web and cannot find the solution to this.  I am developing an ASP.NET application that needs to consume a PeopleSoft web service.  It was working fine until they applied security to the service.  It's not a .NET service, so I cannot pass in credentials in the typical .NET way usnig System.Net.NetworkCredential.  The PS developers told me I have to pass the credentials in the SOAP header.  I see no specific way to do that anywhere.  Here's the snippet from the PeopleSoft WSDL:

```
<wsdl:binding name="PROCESSREQUEST_Binding" type="tns:PROCESSREQUEST_PortType">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> 
- <wsdl:operation name="PRCS_FINDREQUESTS">
  <soap:operation soapAction="PRQ_FINDREQUESTS.v1" style="document" /> 
- <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UsernameTokenSecurityPolicyPasswordRequired" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-    open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
- <wsp:ExactlyOne>
- <wsp:All>
- <wsse:SecurityToken wsp:Usage="wsp:Required" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-    open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:TokenType>wsse:UserNameToken</wsse:TokenType> 
- <Claims>
  <SubjectName MatchType="wsse:Exact" /> 
 <UsePassword wsp:Usage="wsp:Required" /> 
</Claims>
</wsse:SecurityToken>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

How would I pass credentials using C#?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the soap header I use when testing my web services having Username security activated with jMeter :

```
<soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <wsse:Security xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
      <wsse:Username>myUserName</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password>myPassWord</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

It should do the work in C#